# defaultConnectionFactory defined in several projects

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

I was given a couple of ASP.NET projects hosted in Azure cloud:

AzureCommon - sql code based on EntityFramework,

AzureDashboard - server code of web site.

Each project has app.config (web.config) file and defines it's own sql connection settings. What connection settings are used when running the code? Is it using localdb or not in production code?

AzureCommon App.config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

AzureDashboard web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDashboardConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDashboard;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Myadmin;Password=xxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case default constructor of DbContext was using connection string argument. localdb is not used.

```
public partial class MyDashboardContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyDashboardContext()
            : base("name=MyDashboardConnection")
        {
        }
}
```